# Open Multiple files in File Dialog Using VB

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

In windows application using VB, I need to open three xml files one after another from specific path. If first xml file is selected, file dialog pops for next xml.

I tried the below code but it is for selecting files together(i.e, which works like shift + selecting files). But i dont want in this manner, i need to select files one after another. If first xml is selected, file dialog pops for selecting next file. LIKE THIS I NEED TO SELECT THREE FILES. Once it is done file dialog closes.

''''

```
  Private Sub SystemDescriptionToolStripMenuItem_Click()

      OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files *.xml | *.xml"
      OpenFileDialog1.MultiSelect = True
      OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "D:\"
      OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select description files"
      OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

  End Sub
```

''''

Comment: If only there was a fundamental code construct intended to perform an action multiple times.

Comment: You really don't want `MultiSelect = True`. You only want to have the user to select one at a time.

Comment: @Mary  how it is possible to change the code according to the selection is done for first xml and filedialog pops for selecting next xml and next for third.

Comment: @jmcilhinney how it is possible to change the code according to the selection is done for first xml and filedialog pops for selecting next xml and next for third.

Comment: As I implied, you need to use a code construct with the purpose of performing the same action multiple times. How do you usually do something multiple times? It's one of the most fundamental programming concepts so, if you don't know, you need to stop what you're doing and work your way through a beginner tutorial to learn the basics.

Answer (score 2):

To use single select (the default) in the dialog box

```
Private Sub SystemDescriptionToolStripMenuItem_Click()
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files *.xml | *.xml"
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "D:\"
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select description file"
    For i = 1 To 3
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            ProcessXMLFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show($"Error on File #{i}. Try Again")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessXMLFile(path As String)
    'Your code to process the file
End Sub
```

To use multi select, instruct the user to hold down the Ctrl key when clicking on a file in the dialog box.

```
Private Sub SystemDescriptionToolStripMenuItem_Click()
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files *.xml | *.xml"
    OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "D:\"
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select description file"
    Dim files(2) As String
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        files = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
        For Each file In files
            ProcessXMLFile(file)
        Next
    Else
        MessageBox.Show($"Error on selecting files")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kindly help! I tried in this way

Comment: Accepting an answer also let's people know that you don't require any further help without their having to open the thread. Questions with answers where none have been accepted show a box with a green outline while those that have an accepted answer show the box filled in green. For those who answer questions a lot on this site, knowing that which questions need no further information saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

Dim eachXMLfile As String()

eachXMLfile = Directory.GetFiles(my_fold_contains_XML, "*.XML")

For Each item As String In eachXMLfile

(Your set of instructions)

Next

Note:
Make sure that Your <my_fold_contains_XML> contains only Your necessary XML files.